# I want to break sentences using regular expression

Tags: java, regex, split

I have following in string

```
String checker="The United States is a federal union of 50 states. The original 13 states were the successors of the 13 colonies that rebelled against British rule."
```

I want to breakup it into subparts such that

```
String Values[]=new String[20];
Value[0]="The United States is a federal union of 50 states."
Value[1]="The original 13 states were the successors of the 13 colonies that rebelled against British rule."
```

That is I want to split it based on "`.`" how can I do it? remember "`.`" is used for any character in regular expression that's why I got stuck

What to write in

```
values[]=checker.split("regular exprression..........");
```

Comment: breaking sentences in this way can be very fragile so be careful with your input. what if the original 13 states were successors of 13.5 colonies?

Comment: How can there be 13.5 colonies?

Comment: @MatiCicero too good  ........ rofl :P

Comment: @MatiCicero; of course you're correct but my point stands... :)

Comment: @MatiCicero: How about "There were 2.5 million colonists at the time of the Revolutionary war".

Comment: which is the nest way to split sentence

Comment: do you want to preserve the `.`?

Comment: No i want any idea to split sentences

Comment: @PedrodelSol is right. Sentence splitting is a way too complex task.
Breaking in the point in "13.5 colonies", or in "John F. Kennedy" is not desirable. I don't know if your goal is simply to split where you find the `.` character, but if you want to properly split sentences, you'll probably find what you need in this thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478263/java-equivalent-for-python-nltk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\.)
```

For java try `(?<=\\.)`

Try this.Split by this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/20

use a positive lookbehind to make sure the split happens just after `.` or there is a `.` before the point of split.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a split function. The \ is to specify the '.' character

```
for ( String s : checker.split( "\\." ) )
        System.out.println( s );
```